# Async XMLHttpRequest not returning response when followed by code to redirect to another URL in Firefox and Safari

Tags: ajax

I am facing problem with my code in FireFox and Safari as below:

```
xhr = new window['XMLHttpRequest'];
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (done || xhr.readyState != 4) {
return;
}
done = true;
handleResponse(xhr.responseText, callback);
};
}
xhr.open('GET', uri+params, true);
xhr.withCredentials = true; 
xhr.send(null);

function handleResponse(responseText, callback) {
var error;
var result;
try {
result = toucan.JSON.parse(responseText)['result']; //connectedAuth 
logout result.
} catch (ex) {
result = undefined;
}
console.log("Result is" + result);

if (!result) {
var errorCode = 'UnknownError';
var errorMessage = 'An unknown error ocurred';
error = toucan.Base.format('%s: %s', errorCode, errorMessage);
}
invokeCallback(error, callback);
```

}

This is followed by redirection as :window.location.href = "index.php?module=login&method=logout";

However, I am not getting any response back from the request I made if it is followed by redirection in FireFox.
This works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox and is specific to the case when request is followed by redirection.
I do not have control on redirection code to be changed. Is there a way that the browser can be enforced to first complete the request and get the response before going for redirection while keeping the call asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a promise, first create a function that run the ajax call that return the response from your server:

```
    ajax_AuthUser(id,pass){

      return   $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "authUser.php",
        data: { id: id, pass: pass}
      })

    }
```

Second use a done statement:

```
ajax_AuthUser(id,pass)
.done(function(response){
     //check the response here !! maybe  validate the json ?
      var auth = JSON.parse(response)
      if(auth.response == "approved"){
     //do something here
        }else{
     //do other stuff here
             }
          }).fail(function(response){
          //do something if fail
}).always(function(){
 //do something after the call finished
})
```

If you want a live example here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4xhke5pt/1/) that show how promises work

Hope it helps